# Why does Go modify UTC time when passing as a URL param?

Tags: datetime, go

So I'm doing this code.

I create a time, and pass it as an URL parameter. In my handler, I do this.

```
path := //some url + time.Now().String()

// put into url and execute a request. 

updatedAtVar := r.URL.Query()["updated_at"][0]
fmt.Println(updatedAtVar)
```

What is coming out of `time.Now().String()` is something like

`2014-11-17 23:02:03 +0000 UTC`.

What is coming out of `r.URL.Query()["updated_at"][0]` is

`2014-11-17 23:02:03 0000 UTC`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: + is a special character in URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the question should be: Why does the (not shown) query string evaluate the value "2014-11-17 23:02:03 0000 UTC" when accessed?

Since "+" in a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) will be treated as a space when parsed (this is a historic rule) ..

> HTML 5 specifies the following transformation for submitting HTML forms with the "get" method to a web server .. **SPACE is encoded as '+'** or '%20'

.. my hypothesis is the result of accessing the value in URL is really the following:

```
2014-11-17 23:02:03  0000 UTC
                   ^^-- space space
```

A 'correct' URL would be `foo?time=2014-11-17+23:02:03+%2B0000+UTC`, encoding `+` as `%2B` so it is not parsed as a space. An equivalent URL would be generated if using programmatic methods to generate URLs instead of building one by hand / string concatenation.